# Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: No such element

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, junit

**Java Code**:

```
@Test
    public void enterApplicationCerdentials(String userName, String password) {

        WebElement element;
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 100);
        element= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("UserID")));
        System.out.println("--"+element);


         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='userID']")).sendKeys("6776440202");
         driver.findElement(By.name("Password")).sendKeys(password);
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='UserName' and @name='UserName']")).sendKeys("Sydney");
        captureScreen();


**HTML File:**

   <frameset rows="*, 1">
<frame src="Script/Login.asp?">
#document
<html><head>
<body onload="OnLoad()" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" text="#000000" link="#000000" vlink="#000000" alink="#000000">
<div id="login">
<div class="tintedBox" id="loginBox">
<h1></h1>

<form name="form" action="Login.asp?" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="Autologout" value="false">
  <input type="hidden" name="Division" value="">
  <span class="error"></span>
  <table>
      <tbody><tr>
          <td>User ID</td>
          <td><input type="text" size="30" id="UserID" name="UserID" value=""></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Password</td>
          <td><input type="password" size="30" id="Password" name="Password" value=""></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
          <td>Last Name/Location</td>
          <td><input type="text" size="30" id="UserName" name="UserName" value=""></td>
      </tr>
  </tbody></table>
  <br>
  <font color="#d12b2c"><nobr>Your Last Name and Location are now mandatory to access the platform, simply</nobr><br>enter the details in field (e.g. Smith/Perth)</font>
  <br><br>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="SaveLogin" name="SaveLogin" value="SaveLogin"><label for="SaveLogin" id="save">Save my login so you can remember me on my next visit.</label>
  </div>
  <div align="center" style="padding-top:20px">
    <input class="button" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
    <input class="button" type="reset" name="Clear" value="Clear">
    <input class="button" type="submit" name="Recognize" value="Remember me?">
  </div>
```

**Error:**

```
            org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.id: UserID (tried for 100 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
            at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:95)
            at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:272)
            at seleniumPages.Page_LoginMyApplication.enterApplicationCerdentials(Page_LoginMyApplication.java:51)
            at stepDefinitions.StepDefs_DataDrivenLogin.i_login_with_credentials_and(StepDefs_DataDrivenLogin.java:23)
            at ?.I login with credentials "tomsmith" and "***************"(resources/features/DataDrivenLogin.feature:7)
        Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"UserID"}
          (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.103)
          (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628402 (536cd7adbad73a3783fdc2cab92ab2ba7ec361e1),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
        Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
        For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
        Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
        System info: host: 'AP01154W8N', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_191'
        Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
        Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.46.628402 (536cd7adbad73a..., userDataDir: C:\Users\sinham0\AppData\Lo...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:51153}, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, proxy: Proxy(), rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: ignore, unhandledPromptBehavior: ignore, version: 73.0.3683.103, webStorageEnabled: true}
        Session ID: 972c9f27cf1a2e9a5905ba48b3a11e65
        *** Element info: {Using=id, value=UserID}
            at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor10.newInstance(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:372)
            at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:188)
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:315)
            at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:205)
            at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$7.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:201)
            at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$22.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:641)
            at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$22.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:638)
            at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:249)
            at seleniumPages.Page_LoginMyApplication.enterApplicationCerdentials(Page_LoginMyApplication.java:51)
            at stepDefinitions.StepDefs_DataDrivenLogin.i_login_with_credentials_and(StepDefs_DataDrivenLogin.java:23)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:31)
            at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:16)
            at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:25)
            at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:37)
            at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:40)
            at cucumber.api.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:102)
            at cucumber.api.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:83)
            at cucumber.api.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:58)
            at cucumber.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:80)
            at cucumber.runtime.junit.PickleRunners$NoStepDescriptions.run(PickleRunners.java:140)
            at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:68)
            at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:23)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
            at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:73)
            at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:118)
            at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:56)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
            at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UserID field is not a clickable field it's a input field so i will suggest you to use this

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("UserID")));
```

Second one is why you have define the WebElement two times there is no use of it, change your code like this, may this help:-

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("UserID"))).sendKeys(userName);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("Password"))).sendKeys(password);
captureScreen();
```

If the `<table>` tag is inside the `frame` tag then try this:-

- if you know the frame name-

  `driver.switchTo().frame("XYZ");`
- If you don't know frame name or number of frames on page-

  `int size = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")).size();`
  it will give you the number of frame on your page then you can directly switch to your frame by index value-

  `driver.switchTo().frame(i);` where i=1,2,3.....

Comment: I tried above code:

Comment: I tried the same above code getting below error 

org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.id: UserID (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)


Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"UserID"}
  (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.103)

Comment: It should work if it's directly on page, may be your ```<table>``` tag is inside the ```Iframe```  so i will suggest you to kindly recheck you DOM correctly.

Comment: HTML:   <frameset rows="*, 1">
<frame src="Script/Login.asp?">
#document
<html><head>
<body onload="OnLoad()" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" text="#000000" link="#000000" vlink="#000000" alink="#000000">
<div id="login">
<div class="tintedBox" id="loginBox">
<h1></h1>

<form name="form" action="Login.asp?" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="Autologout" value="false">
  <input type="hidden" name="Division" value="">
  <span class="error"></span>

Comment: <table>
      <tbody><tr>
          <td>User ID</td>
          <td><input type="text" size="30" id="UserID" name="UserID" value=""></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Password</td>
          <td><input type="password" size="30" id="Password" name="Password" value=""></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
          <td>Last Name/Location</td>
          <td><input type="text" size="30" id="UserName" name="UserName" value=""></td>
      </tr>
  </tbody></table>

Comment: Upkar Singh Could you Please what would be correct Code

Comment: then first of all you must switch to iframe then it will work, to switch on iFrame use this - ```driver.switchTo().frame("XYZ");```

Comment: Upkar Singh, What is "XYZ". its frame name?

Comment: This is the frame ID name, i just commented before so i was not able to see your code.

Comment: please attach your HTML code to the question, then i will able to understand it.

Comment: Upkar Singh, I have modified my HTML code. Could u please give me help me

Comment: you just try ```driver.switchTo().frame(0);```

Comment: My pleasure, please mark answer as a usefull.